# Summing to columns together in a Flux query?

Tags: influxdb

I am trying to use InfluxDB and Grafana to plot the energy usage in my house. The sensor I'm using reports energy consumption (in watts) separately for each leg of my split-phase electrical service. I don't care about the individual values of the legs ("energy_active_power_a" and "energy_active_power_b"), just the sum of the two.

How do I combine these two columns? I'm pretty comfortable with ANSI SQL, but this Flux stuff is like a foreign language to me.

```
from(bucket: "homeassistant")
|> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "W")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["domain"] == "sensor")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["entity_id"] == "energy_active_power_a" or r["entity_id"] ==     "energy_active_power_b")
|> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
|> yield(name: "mean")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from(bucket: "homeassistant")
|> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "W")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["domain"] == "sensor")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["entity_id"] == "energy_active_power_a" or r["entity_id"] ==     "energy_active_power_b")
|> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
|> pivot(rowKey:["_time"], columnKey: ["entity_id"], valueColumn: "_value")
|> map(fn: (r) => ({ r with
  total: r.energy_active_power_a + r.energy_active_power_b
}))
|> drop(columns:["energy_active_power_a", "energy_active_power_b"])
|> yield(name: "mean")
```